# How to set conditions in the parallel build to proceed to next stage if one step is success

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a declarative pipeline in Jenkins. There are 6 stages in it.

1. First Stage: Scenario Upload
2. Second Stage: Pull code from Git
3. Third Stage: Maven Build
4. Fourth Stage: Its a parallel stage. First step will launch mobile emulator and second step will check device connected or not.
5. Fifth Stage: I want to start this stage when the second step BUILD SUCCESS else stop the job
6. Sixth Stage: Send email

I am stuck with point 5 (Fifth Stage). Please help

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Scenario Upload") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'CyclosAppStatus.xlsx')]
                    new hudson.FilePath(new File("$workspace/Cucumber_BDD master/Result/CyclosAppStatus.xlsx")).copyFrom(inputFile)
                    inputFile.delete()    
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Git Pull Code') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: '708a126a-66bb-4eb5-8826-55cedf6497c3', url: 'https://github.com/divakar-ragupathy/Mobile_Automation_BDD.git'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Maven Clean Build') {
            steps {
                bat label: '', script: '''Echo Maven Clean Build...
                        cd %WORKSPACE%\\ADB_Devices
                        mvn clean compile'''
            }
        }
        
        stage('Building Android Setup') {
            steps {
                parallel(
                    Invoke_Emulator: {
                        bat label: '', script: '''Echo Invoking Emulator...
                                    @echo off
                                    set emulName=%Emulator_Name%
                                    echo %emulName%
                                    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%e in ("%emulName%") do (
                                      %ANDROID_AVD_PATH%emulator -avd "%%e" -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot-save -no-snapshot-load
                                      )
                                    endlocal'''
                    },
                    
                    Checking_Device: {
                        bat label: '', script: '''Echo Checking Connected Device...
                        cd %WORKSPACE%\\ADB_Devices
                        mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.expleo.adbListner.CheckConnectedAdbDevices -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///%WORKSPACE%\\ADB_Devices\\src\\log4j.properties -Dexec.args="%Emulator_Name%"'''
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable without the "def" keyword it is global. You can use that to store the condition in the previous stages. In the 5th stage you can use a [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) block to check this condition.